# Log Kodaira dimension of Briekorn varities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, kodaira-dimension

Is there any formula or estimate of the log-Kodaira dimension of the Brieskorn variety $V_{a_0,\ldots,a_n}:=\{x_0^{a_0}+\ldots + x_n^{a_n}=1\}$ for $2\le a_0\le \ldots \le a_n$.

In particular, I wonder if the following claim holds: if $a_i\le b_i$ for all $i$, then the log-Kodaira dimension of $V_{a_0,\ldots,a_n}$ is not greater than the log-Kodaira dimension of $V_{b_0,\ldots,b_n}$.